# Stream in StreamBuilder not recreated when setting state

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, flutter-web

I run the following code in a Flutter Web project

```dart
  void initState() {
    reloadTimer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 30),
      (timer) => setState(() {
        Fimber.d('setting state in widget');
      }),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => StreamBuilder<List<Timetable?>>(
        stream: widget.service
            .getTimetable()
            .where((list) => list.isNotEmpty),
        builder: (context, snapshot) => Column(
            // ...
        ),
  );
```

and the stream is created like that

```dart
  @override
  Stream<List<Timetable?>> getTimetable() {
    final minDateEpoch = DateTime.now()
        .subtract(const Duration(minutes: 5))
        .millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    Fimber.d('getting new stream for ${minDateEpoch.toString()}');

    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('rides')
        .where('canceled', isEqualTo: false)
        .where('departureTimeEpoch', isGreaterThan: minDateEpoch)
        .orderBy('departureTimeEpoch')
        .limit(100)
        .snapshots()
        .asyncMap((element) => element.toTimetableList());
  }
```

now in the logs I get

```
2022-12-14T15:38:34.867 D       Flutter:         getting new stream for 1671028414658
2022-12-14T15:39:04.704 D       Flutter:         setting state in widget
2022-12-14T15:39:34.727 D       Flutter:         setting state in widget
2022-12-14T15:40:04.734 D       Flutter:         setting state in widget
```

which indicates that `setState` has been run but the stream hasn't been recreated although `setState` should rebuild the whole widget and therefore also the stream. What am I missing here?

Btw, I know that this example is somehow nonsense. In my real project, I want to recreate the stream every 3-4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code the `StreamBuilder` widget does not depend on the state, since you use `widget.service...` in the `stream` parameter. The widget itself is immutable (only it's state can change) so `setState` won't have an effect.

Instead, declare a late member in the state class:

```
late Stream<List<Timetable?>> _stream;
```

In `initState` assign a value to it:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _stream = widget.service.getTimetable...
}
```

Use this member in the `StreamBuilder`:

```
stream: _stream,
```

After this, if you assign a new value to `_stream` in `setState`, it will trigger a rebuild:

```
setState(() => _stream = widget.service.getTimetable...);
```